# Can I create one layout constraint in interface builder and then apply it to multiple controls

Tags: ios, autolayout

Can I create one layout constraint in interface builder and then apply it to multiple controls?
I mean just use interface builder and don't write code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the interface builder workflow is dragging some controls to a viewcontroller firstly and then apply constraints to them. But some constraints like width ,height,leading and trailing space to their superview can be applied to multi controls.Change that constraint will effect all the controls that applied it. Just like applying css to html component.I think if xcode's interface builder can provide such function, maybe in sometimes it's more effective.

You can't apply the same constraint to multiple views. However, you can achieve "cascading" constraints (so you can adjust one thing in interface builder, and everything else moves) by creating your constraints carefully.

Say you have a stack of buttons, which you want to be all the same width and left / right aligned. Create a constraint on the top button pinning it to the edge of the superview, and another one, giving it a particular width.

For the other buttons in the stack, don't create width and position constraints, but simply pin the left and right edges of the button to the left and right edges of the button above. This way, the whole stack will follow whatever changes you make to the top button.

Another alternative is to use container views, and have your position and sizing constraints on the container view and just make the subviews pin to the edges. The best approach depends on the final layout you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You said "For the other buttons in the stack, don't create width and position constraints, but simply pin the left and right edges of the button to the left and right edges of the button above". But I don't know  what to do to achieve that. Could you give me a detailed step by step guide? Thank you!

Comment: Try my blog post here, though this only applies to Xcode 4, the UI for pinning is pretty similar: http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/18/autolayout-in-interface-builder/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read more on auto layout. You cannot create all possible constraints in IB. Constraints are objects but you cannot change what views they are related to. 
They are not mutable. 
You can adjust the constant and the multiplier at run time.

Comment: I know what your means.I have readed the auto layout guide and manual. Now the interface builder workflow is  dragging some controls to a viewcontroller firstly and then apply constraints to them. But some constraints like width ,height,leading and trailing space to their superview  can be applied to multi controls.Change that constraint will effect all the controls that applied it. Just like applying css to html component.I think if xcode's interface builder can provide such function, maybe in sometimes it's more effective.

Comment: Yeah, it would be very convenient. I also get the CSS feeling from Auto Layout, but it's still new and clumsy. Unfortunately the view(s) in a constraint are not currently mutable. When you change views, you need to add constraints. You can however make custom views that apply their own height and width constraints (because these do not rely on anything outside the "self" view hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that in Interface Builder.  You should learn the Auto Layout Visual Format Language, which does let you apply similar constraints to multiple views in one pass.

Here's [the official guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html).

[This blog post](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/) has a great introduction, and many helpful examples.